# Do I need the Android SDK and a game engine or just the game engine?

Tags: android

I'm using LibGDX for the game engine so I need to know, If I'm creating a game for android, do I need the Android SDK AND LibGDX, or just LibGDX?

Edit: I'm probably going to be using Eclipse or Netbeans

Comment: I suggest using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create **APK** file without Android SDK, so you will need to have both.